# First Steps on Win7 and Instrumentation

Tags: windows-7, instrumentation

Hello as showed in the last pdc, we as developers can take advantage of SO capabilities and  add instrumentation to our code (based on best practices). 
So in that session they introduce the new Windows PowerShell-based troubleshooting platform, and how it enables you to easily monitor multiple data sources to empower the end user and IT pro to detect and resolve software problems. But the demo was never uploaded, and I want to know how to "write-code" using Instrumentation on Win7 or How to demostrate with some prof tools how my code help to improve software quality.

I Also try the Windows 7 for Developers Training Kit, but demo is apparently not using WMI

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this place to be a good place to start. [Windows 7 Training Kit](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/06/12/windows-7-rc-training-kit-for-developers.aspx)

Comment: I try that, but the demo apparently is not using WMI Apis :(